Webdriverio throws an error when I use inheritance
Hi When I use inheritance in webdriverio I get the following error:
ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on browser object that is not fully initialized.
[0-0] browser object has only capabilities and some flags like isMobile.
[0-0] Helper files that use other browser commands have to be moved to before hook.
Here is the classes am using:
export default class Page{
    async waitForSeconds(seconds:number){
        await browser.pause(seconds * 1000);
    }
}


class HomePage extends Page{
    
    //Here comes the selectors
    get signInEntryButton(){
        return $('#signin_button');
    }

    get feedbackLink(){
        return $('#feedback');
    }

    //here comes the functions 
     async open(path:string){
         return browser.url(path);
     }

     async openSingInPage(){
        await this.signInEntryButton.click();
     }
     async clickFeedBackLink(){
        await this.feedbackLink.click();
     }
}
export default new HomePage();


import HomePage from "../pageobjects/HomePage.ts";
import LoginPage from "../pageobjects/LoginPage.ts";
import FeedBackPage from "../pageobjects/FeedBackPage.ts";

describe("My first test using Page objects pattern", ()=> {

    // beforeEach(async()=>{
    //     await browser.url('http://zero.webappsecurity.com/index.html');
    // });

    it("Should not loging with invalid Credentials", async () => {
        await HomePage.open('http://zero.webappsecurity.com/index.html');
        await HomePage.openSingInPage();
        
        await LoginPage.assertLoginPageIsVisible();
        await LoginPage.login();

        expect(LoginPage.errorLoginMessage).toHaveText('Login and/or password are wrong.');
        await LoginPage.waitForSeconds(3);
    });
});

